# How do I vary the distribution of vertex heights with a seed in Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, random-seed, terrain

I'm currently making a Three.JS script that can generate a continent-like shape using Perlin noise, but I'm unsure of how to make the script distribute the shapes unevenly for a more realistic portrayal of the continent. How should I go about implementing the seed variable into the generation in such a way that the distribution is more varied?

Here's an image to what it can generate right now.

[image: Here's an image to what it can generate right now.]

```
  var perlin = new Perlin();
  var peak = 150;
  var smoothing = 900;
  var myseed = Math.random(1000);

  var vertices = terrain.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  for (var i = 0; i <= vertices.length; i += 3) {
    vertices[i + 2] =
      peak * perlin.noise(vertices[i] / smoothing, vertices[i + 1] / smoothing);
  }
  terrain.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  terrain.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  return terrain;
}
```

(Repo: https://github.com/chaoszeroomega/IslandGenerator )

Comment: I think this is usually achieved by adding multiple calls to perlin noise at different frequencies (multiples of vertex x y in your example)

so something like:
vertices[i + 2] =
      peak * perlin.noise(vertices[i] / smoothing, vertices[i + 1] / smoothing);
+ (peak * .5 * perlin.noise(vertices[i] * 10. / smoothing , vertices[i + 1] * 10. / smoothing);

Comment: There are several examples with terrain: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=terr#webgl_geometry_terrain And another option: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-noisejs/3449?u=prisoner849

Comment: As you're using `PlaneGeometry() / PlaneBufferGeoemtry()`, use data of uv coordinates instead of position coordinates.